Ошибка при добавлении в переменную данных из БД
Всем здравствуйте! У меня есть форма на которой я хочу выбрав отдельные товары, посчитать сумму их цен. Я решил добавить каждую цену из каждой таблицы в переменные, а после их сложить, вывести в ещё одну переменную, а в заключении добавить эту переменную в TextBlock.Text. Но при переходе на эту форму, у меня появляется ошибка,

System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
KOMP.App.CurrentPr.get вернул null.

Я не понимаю, почему появляется ошибка, логично что при открытии формы, ещё не выбрав никакой из товаров, в TextBlock'е и во всех переменных будет значение 0. Я думал что у меня просто будут хранится переменные с этими нулевыми значениями, а уже потом, по мере выбора товара, у меня будет меняться сумма. Но не успеваю выбрать, сразу при открытии формы вылезает данная ошибка.
Я думал что возможно нужно создатиь переменную которая будет просто хранить эти значения, но ничего в интернете не нашел.. По этому прошу помощи.
var PrPrice = App.CurrentPr.Price;
var CSPrice = App.CurrentCS.Price;
var MbPrice = App.CurrentMb.Price;
var RAMPrice = App.CurrentRAM.Price;
var VCPrice = App.CurrentVC.Price;
var PUPrice = App.CurrentPU.Price;
var CoPrice = App.CurrentCo.Price;
var TPPrice = App.CurrentTP.Price;
var MiPrice = App.CurrentMi.Price;
var KbPrice = App.CurrentKb.Price;
var CaPrice = App.CurrentCa.Price;
var HphPrice = App.CurrentHph.Price;
var HDDPrice = App.CurrentHDD.Price;
var SSDPrice = App.CurrentSSD.Price;
var JoyPrice = App.CurrentJoy.Price;
var MoPrice = App.CurrentMo.Price;

int[] sumi = { PrPrice, CSPrice, MbPrice, RAMPrice, VCPrice, PUPrice, CoPrice, TPPrice, MiPrice, KbPrice, CaPrice, HphPrice, HDDPrice, SSDPrice, JoyPrice, MoPrice };

var SUM = sumi.Sum();

Summa.Text = Convert.ToString(SUM);

App.CurrentPr.Price - это ссылка на таблицу в базе где я беру поле с ценой (Price)
int[] sumi - вот это я решил создать переменную с масивом в котором будут все до этого созданные переменные.
var SUM = sumi.Sum(); - это я суммирую все переменные вместе, создавая сумму всех цен выбранных товаров.
Summa.Text = Convert.ToString(SUM); - тут я добавляю переменную в TextBlock с x:Name="Summa", перед этим конвертируя полученное число в строку.
Ошибка возникает на первой же строке: var PrPrice = App.CurrentPr.Price;
Прошу обьяснить почему появляется ошибка, как её можно устранить, или же как можно модернизировать код, чтобы всё работало корректно. Спасибо за ответы.
